# Twilio Sync - Does Twilio Sync support event handler removing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I'm developing an application using Twilio Sync as a database. I do subscribe to a lot of events such as `itemAdded`, `itemUpdated`, `itemRemoved` to get real-time update functionality on client-side using Sync Javascript SDK. But I don't see documentation mentioning anything about how to remove these event handlers. Is it possible to do so?

For my use case, let's say we have a List view. When you click on each item in a list, it will create an event handler and attach it with a Twilio Sync document related to the list item. But if user clicks the list multiple times, the application will create multiple event handlers attached to the document without removing/destroying the old handler.

For me, it seems to be a very simple thing. Maybe documentation had mentioned it somewhere but I missed it? Or is TwilioSync not meant to be used as a main database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Sync objects inherit from `EventEmitter` so if you need to remove a listener you need to call [`obj.removeListener(eventName, listener)`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener).

Alternatively, perhaps you could program your interface code to only add a listener to an object on the first tap?